# Should multiple entries in Petra be on conscutive days when buying a Jordan pass?

Tags: jordan, petra

There is 3 different [Jordan pass](https://www.jordanpass.jo/contents/Prices.aspx) and the only difference between them is the number of allowed entries in Petra.

However, I'd like to know if the entries **must** be on consecutive days ?

I tried to email the Jordan Ministry of Tourism but they never answered. I only found [this discussion](https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/ShowTopic-g318895-i8977-k9629577-Jordan_Pass_Question_for_Petra-Petra_Wadi_Musa_Ma_in_Governorate.html) but I'd like a more reliable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just back from Petra after buying a 3 days pass.

I was allowed to enter on Day 1 and Day 2 (consecutive days).

However, I came back 4 days later and the watchman's PDA clearly displays "Invalid pass". However, the guy told me that as I had a 3 day pass, I could enter.

So, I don't know if he just doesn't care (my pass was not even checked the second day) or if it's forbidden.

For future readers, be careful especially if you have the 2-days pass and you expect not to go in Petra 2 days on a row. Also, feel free to answer with your own experience

Answer (score 1):

The first FAQ entry (https://www.jordanpass.jo/contents/FAQs.aspx) tell us

> (...)  Repeat entry is not allowed unless for Petra if you buy the Jordan Explorer and Jordan Expert Packages.

So I assume that you can visit Petra on non consecutive days, and the check is done just at entry of Petra valley (not in the town). So it is the number of daily passes.

Also term and condition (https://www.jordanpass.jo/contents/Terms_and_Conditions.aspx) doesn't have anything. And for the link: https://www.jordanpass.jo/contents/Opening_Hours.aspx , so night spectacles are not within valid opening times (for pass).

Comment: Seems fair, thank you. I'll confirm once I'll be back from Jordan =)